# How to write lucene search to find record containing part of word

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I am using lucene search to find records.
I am able to search for any string starting with string

```
LuceneQuery: {+(+nodeName:cen*^4.0)}
```

My words are:

- Lucene
- Cent
- Excentric
- Percent

How do I return all of them because the query I am using is returning only 1 record ?

```
 <add name="DocumentSearchSearcher" type="UmbracoExamine.UmbracoExamineSearcher, UmbracoExamine"
          analyzer="Lucene.Net.Analysis.WhitespaceAnalyzer, Lucene.Net"
          enableLeadingWildcards="true"/>
```

Comment: Try searching for `*cen*` not `cen*`.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev *cen* will not render (first thing I have checked when used in luke )

Comment: What do you mean, "will not render"?

Comment: The query using *cen* is not valid lucene string

Comment: _cen_ seems to me a valid Lucene query. What error do you get? What's the exact query you tried with Luke? Did you enable leading wildcards in Luke?